# Why is Jasmine not resetting a spy when spying on $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, jasmine, spy

I am trying to spy on `$.ajax` in Jasmine 2.0 tests. Here is a simplified example (TypeScript) showing my scenario:

```
describe("first test", () => {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake((uri: string, settings: JQueryAjaxSettings) => {
        return deferred.resolve("ThisIsADummyResult");
    });

    it("should return dummy result", done => {
        $.ajax("http://somedummyserver.net").then(result => {
            expect(result).toBe("ThisIsADummyResult");
            done();
        });
    });
});

describe("second test", () => {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake((uri: string, settings: JQueryAjaxSettings) => {
        return deferred.resolve("ThisIsAnotherResult");
    });

    it("should return another result", done => {
        $.ajax("http://somedummyserver.net").then(result => {
            expect(result).toBe("ThisIsAnotherResult");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

`firstTest` as well as `second test` work if I run them alone. However, if I run both tests as shown above, I get the following error message: `ajax has already been spied upon`.

So my questions are:

- Shouldn't the spies be reset by Jasmine after each test automatically? Why doesn't that work in my case?
- Is there another way of using `spyOn` which makes Jasmine reset the spies?
- How can I manually reset the spies?

**Update:** I continued experimenting and found a possible solution myself. If I set up the spies inside of the `it` spec, both tests run fine. Here is the code for `first test` showing what I mean:

```
describe("first test", () => {
    it("should return dummy result", done => {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake((uri: string, settings: JQueryAjaxSettings) => {
            return deferred.resolve("ThisIsADummyResult");
        });

        $.ajax("http://somedummyserver.net").then(result => {
            expect(result).toBe("ThisIsADummyResult");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Still, it would be very interesting why the first version does not work. Why does Jasmine not reset the spies in the first version whereas it does in the second one?

Answer (score 2):

For stuff that is used across all tests but you need it reset for each test use 'beforeEach' : http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown

Jasmine does not magically know which lines of your describe body you want reevaluated for each 'it' block.